# Can Edit & Continue work for VS 2010, ASP.Net MVC application on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010, on a 64-bit OS, and a large solution with multiple projects. The main one is an ASP.NET MVC 3 project.

I am trying to enable "Edit and Continue" but I'm not having any luck. I have followed all the steps outlined here:

http://hobby.keluargareski.net/2010/05/17/how-to-enable-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio/

and have targeted x86 in all my projects. I receive a dialog box stating:

"Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded"

Has anyone had any success with a similar setup? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure you're not debugging.  I got this error as well then I realized it was debugging.  Either stop debugging or detach then make your changes.

Comment: The point of this IS to make changes while you debug.

Answer (score 2):

The message "Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded" means that the code you're trying to change is not in an assembly visual studio can find/has built. Maybe you're trying to debug a class which is not compiled into the binary. When you have multiple projects and the class you are trying to debug is in one which is not set for building in that configuration. Go to Debug -> Configuration Manager and verify you have the check box ticked for the project you're debugging.

Check the output path of your binaries and make sure they all go to a directory which can be found by the calling assembly, i.e. you can try putting all assemblies to the same directory.

Also you can refresh your references to the project in question by removing a reference and then adding it back, as visual studio can sometimes be buggy in this way.

Hope this helps, as it's quite a generic problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

Generic problem is right :(  I haven't figured it out in one of my Solutions, but in another I did finally find out what I was doing "wrong".

My Solution has a Project for Windows, and a Project for WindowsPhone.  My problem was that the auto-load for recently edited files was loading my code files from my WindowsPhone project rather than my Windows project.  So, when I would pause my code in Windows, it wouldn't let me Edit&Continue because the code file "belongs to a different project".  So, I closed the code file, and then re-opened it from my Windows project.  Finally it let me do Edit&Continue.

Now I have to figure out why my other Solution doesn't work for E&C.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered this problem for a while.  This post http://sciagaprogramisty.blogspot.com/2012/09/changes-are-not-allowed-if-assembly-has.html solved it for me... specifically the last image, which instructs you to change your output path to just "bin\"

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That didn't work for me...